# how to access props in module exports

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Hey I want segregate the events into a separate file. So I did

```
import React from 'react';

var eventHandler = {
  execute: (methodName) => {
    eventHandler[`${methodName}`]();
  },
  login: (props) => {
    console.log(`login -> event handler called....!`);
    props.navigation.navigate('Home', { name: 'Om' })
  },

  google: () => {
    console.log(`google -> event handler called....!`);
  },

  facebook: () => {
    console.log(`facebook -> event handler called....!`);
  },
};

module.exports = eventHandler;
```

But here in module.exports there is no props available. Props is always undefined.

I just want to navigate to other screens from here. But it's not working.

Comment: Where is the value of `props` supposed to come from? ```eventHandler[`${methodName}`]();``` You don't pass any arguments when you call the function.

Comment: @Quentin props is a react native thing. I should not pass that but by default it should be available. I assumed its like `args`.

Comment: No. Props have to be passed explicitly when you call a function unless you are using JSX (in which case the attributes on the component become the entries on the props object).

Comment: @Quentin I'm a beginner and I referred this link https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react#props . I'm not getting why i need to pass props explicitly.

Comment: ```eventHandler[`${methodName}`]();``` is not the same as `<Cat name="Maru" />`! (Which is literally what I explained in my previous comment)

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for your time kindly have a look at this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating#navigating-to-a-new-screen   the props has navigation by default. and they are not passing it.

Comment: So that's special-casing as described — [Each screen component in your app is provided with the navigation prop automatically … It's important to highlight the navigation prop is not passed in to all components; only screen components receive this prop automatically!](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/) — You don't have a component here, let alone a *screen* component.

Comment: @Quentin I stuck here totally So I asked this question. What to do now is there any alternative approach for this ?

Comment: Pass `navigation` when you call the function!

Comment: @Quentin I just changed my architecture itself. Passing navigation and method name is a very expensive thing. But that's the only way which solves the problem